# error: relation "equalityfits" does not exist

Tags: mysql, postgresql, express

I am following a tutorial on how to set up the PERN stack except i am using yarn. I currently have it where when i run yarn start on my front end it also boots up the express server and i also have a database.js that contains

```
    user: "admin",
    password: "MYPW",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 5432,
    database: "equalityfits"
```

I have a user named admin that is the owner of a database called equalityfits(no upper case), but when i send a post request to connect and insert something into the database it just says that the relation "equalityfits" does not exist. Here is a picture of the current databases.
[image]

Here is the server.js with the endpoint:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = 5000;
const cors = require("cors");
const pool = require("./db")

//
//Middleware
//
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());


//
//Routes
//

//Add to cart
app.post("/addCart", async(req,res) =>{
    try {
        const { description } = req.body;
        const newName =pool.query("INSERT INTO equalityfits (name) VALUES(TEST)", [description]);
        res.json(newName);

    } catch(err){
        console.error(err);
    }
});

app.listen(PORT, () =>{
    console.log("Express Server has started on port", {PORT});
});
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: The error is not on your connection, but the insert. A 'relation' is a table not a database.  What does "\dt" show? You connect to databases but insert (select, update,delete) tables.

Comment: @Belayer Ahhhh that makes sense, so INSERT INTO (table name) (column name) VALUES(value to be inputed into column)?